# How to select the session variables created in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have created a variable named `value(set @value="variable123")` and used it in many queries.

its working fine, but how can I select these variables (like procedures we have a statement show procedure status).

When I executed "show variables", I did not get variables which I have created.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you [can not](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=56520) do it - because of variables definition principles.

Comment: HI Alma,then how can we access the variables if you forget its name.What is the validity of that variable?

Comment: I guess you can not. Unfortunately, since variables themselves are a weird thing in MySQL, there's only one solution - do not forget your variable's names.